# probability about the bulb with replacement

Tags: probability, statistics, probability-distributions

I encounter this question

In a lot of 50 light bulbs, there are 2 bad bulbs. If we selected five bulbs and replace it after recording the results.
(a)  Find the probability of at least 1 defective bulb among the 5. (With
replacement)

(b)  How many bulbs at least should he examine so that the probability of
finding at least 1 bad bulb exceeds 80%?

My attempt:
part (a), i find the probability by 1 - ((48C1)^(5) / (50C1)^(5)), is it correct? I'm not sure and think that there may be mistakes in it.

part (b), base on part (a) and let n be the no. of bulbs he should examine at least,
I try to calculate like this: 1 - ((48Cn)^(5) / (50Cn)^(5)) > 80%
((48Cn)^(5) / (50Cn)^(5)) < 0.2
LHS= ((48! / n!(48-n)!)^5) / ((50! / n!(50-n)!)^5)
then I am not sure is it right or not and if it is right how can i continue to find the value of n as i stuck with it.

Comment: Welcome to MSE.  Please use [MathJax](https://www.onemathematicalcat.org/MathJaxDocumentation/TeXSyntax.htm) to format your posts.  To begin with, surround math expressions (including numbers) with `$` signs and use `_` for subscripts.  `$x_1$` comes out as $x_1$.

Comment: "*selected five bulbs and replace it after recording the results*"  By this, do you mean we take a single bulb, then put it back, then take a second bulb and put it back, then take a third bulb and put it back, etc... Or do you mean that you take the first bulb and then the second bulb without putting any back yet until after the fifth bulb is taken?

Comment: As a stylistic choice... do not ever use `nC1`... just write $n$.  There is no reason why you should be writing (48C1)^(5) / (50C1)^(5) rather than 48^5/50^5.  "*Choosing one*" does not need to be written as a binomial coefficient.  It needlessly convolutes what you have written.  The only times where I would encourage you to write a binomial coefficient where you are choosing one thing is if by including it it is easier to spot a pattern, such as $\binom{n}{0}+\binom{n}{1}+\binom{n}{2}+\dots+\binom{n}{n}$

Comment: Now... as for your answers... to know for sure I need to hear your response to my first comment asking for clarification, but it sounds like all selections are done with replacement after each individual bulb being pulled.  In such a scenario, your answer to (a) is correct but your answer to (b) you have performed the calculation as though you changed the rules about replacement when it sounds like you shouldn't have.  You should also have had $1-(48/50)^n$ here.  As for finding the minimum value of $n$ such that $1-(48/50)^n>0.8$... consider the usage of logarithms.

Comment: I think it should be the first one since this question also include parts asking the probability that are selected randomly and without replacement before the question I posted here. as I don't have problem with that part I just ask the with replacement question here. @JMoravitz

Comment: However, in such an inspection scheme, it is very inefficient to use sampling with replacement. So your intuition to use sampling without replacement is on track--even if not for this particular textbook problem. See Note in my Answer.

Answer (score 1):

@JMoravitz has given good advice in Comments. I will give some answers from R. I will leave it to you to see if your work matches my results:

(a) The number $X$ of defective bulbs among five tested with replacement has $X \sim\mathsf{Binom}(n=5, p=2/50),$ You seek $P(X \ge 1) = 1 - P(X=0) = 1 - (24/25)^5 = 0.1846273.$ In R, a binomial PDF is denoted by `dbinom`. I'll show two computations:

```
1 - (48/50)^5
[1] 0.1846273
1 - dbinom(0, 5, 2/50)
[1] 0.1846273
```

(b) Now you want $r$ such that $1 - (24/25)^r > .8$ By using logs you can find that $r=40$ is just enough, as verified in R below.

```
1 - dbinom(0, 39, 2/50)
[1] 0.7964936
1 - dbinom(0, 40, 2/50)
[1] 0.8046338
```

In R, one might search among numbers $n = 5$ through $100$
to find the right answer as shown below, where we seek
to make the probability of discovering no bad bulbs to be less than $0.2.$

```
n = 5:100
p.0 = dbinom(0, n, 2/50)
r = min(n[p.0 < .2]);  r
[1] 40
```

*Note:* In practice, it would make no sense to sample with replacement. Sampling without replacement, we would
use a hypergeometric distribution.

Then the probability of at least one bad bulb among $5$ chosen without replacement is

```
1 - phyper(0,  2,48,  5)
[1] 0.1918367
```

Then sampling $r = 28$ will be just enough have probability above $0.8$
of finding a bad bulb. For this kind of 'inspection',
sampling without replacement is noticeably more efficient.

```
n = 5:50  # only 50 bulbs available
p.0 = dhyper(0, 2, 48, n)
r = min(n[p.0 < .2]);  r
[1] 28    # fewer than for sampling with replacement
1 - dhyper(0, 2, 48, 28)
[1] 0.8114286
1 - dhyper(0, 2, 48, 27)
[1] 0.7934694
```

The relevant hypergeometric probability is

$$P(X = 0) = \frac{{2 \choose 0}{48\choose 28}}{{50\choose 28}} = \frac{22(21)}{50(49)} =    0.1885714 < 0.2.$$

[In computation of hypergeometric probabilities, it is often important to
simplify expressions (as above) in order to avoid factorials
too large for ordinary computer (or calculator) arithmetic
to handle. Or to use logarithms.]